# Run Java-applets directly ( without html page )

Tags: java, applet

I have  a problem.

How i can run my java-applet directly without embedded in my web page?

I know appletViewr can execute applet without a browser but I need to get java applet without html page.

Comment: AppletViewr execute applet ojut of browser but i need to get java applet without html page

Answer (score 7):

Use below code with your code, where AppletClass is your Applet class.

```
AppletClass appletClass = new AppletClass ();

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
frame.add(appletClass );

// Set frame size and other properties
...

// Call applet methods
appletClass .init();
appletClass .start();

frame.setVisible(true);
```

More customizations can be done as required.

Comment: Any idea how to pass <PARAM> values?

Comment: @KeithTyler combine the above code, which goes in a `public static void main(String[] args)` with the stub approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6131260).

Answer (score 5):

Appletviewer is the way to go, BUT, **it still requires a webpage with an applet-tag**.

An alternative solution is to write a stub class, with a main method, that instantiates the applet, calls `init()`, `start()`, `stop()` and `destroy()` as would otherwise have been done by the browser or appletviewer.

Answer (score 1):

Run `appletviewer [ options  ] urls ..`.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/appletviewer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Build a subclass, which implements main-method, and call init(), start(), stop(), destroy as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use eclipse: Right-Click on your main java file (the one which extends Applet), select the 'Run As' submenu, and select 'Applet.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/*<applet code="java file name " height=150 width=150></applet>*/`
before declaring applet class and then compile java program and run applet by using appletviewer it execute perfectly don't require any html file

Answer (score 0):

This browser extension works quite well. Supports Chrome and Edge.

https://leaningtech.com/cheerpj-applet-runner/

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score -1):

```
<applet code=classname height=200 width=200>

</applet>
```

Simply write this code in your java program and first run using:

```
javac classname.java
```

after

```
run:appletviewer classname.java
```

Comment: Consider avoiding all uppercase, and use code tags where appropriate.