# Setting Applet parameters with Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, parameters, applet

So I was playing around with Java's Reflection API. I wanted to try loading a simple Java applet I found on the internet. Now what I got stumbled upon was applet parameters:

```
<param name="aparam" value="12345">
```

Is there a way to do the exact same thing via Java Reflection?

Comment: *"simple Java applet I found on the internet"* The internet is a big place, at what URL did you find the applet?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do the exact same thing via Java Reflection?

No.  Or rather, if you design an [applet stub](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletStub.html) and attach it to the applet it can provide whatever parameters you want, without using any reflection.

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6131260/418556) I made previously.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example on how to do it via an applet stub?