# Viewing a java applet outside of the browser without appletviewer

Tags: java, applet

I found some old published [java applets](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/InteractProgs/index.htm). Ideally, it would be great to run that in the browser but newer versions of Chrome (which my students have) makes running Java applets nearly impossible.

I can't expect all my students to have appletviewer since it's deprecated and not shipped with newer versions of the JDK. Is there an easy way to create a wrapper to start a java Swing frame that can start the applet? I've tried looking at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129825/embed-a-3rd-party-japplet-in-a-swing-gui-pass-it-parameters/6131260#6131260) and [this guide](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.applet/implementsAppletStub.htm) but I don't think I have the right incantation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The last time I wrote an applet was in 1997.  Are you sure that they are still relevant?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Some processes in the governments still utilize that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consider using CheerpJ Applet Runner, available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein) and [Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/ebfcpaoldmijengghefpohddmfpndmic)

It is an easy to use, single click extension that can run legacy Java applets in modern browsers securely and without requiring any additional software.

Full disclosure, I am CTO of Leaning Technologies and lead developer of the CheerpJ technology.

The CheerpJ Applet Runner extension is free for educational/personal use, but please note that any other use requires a license. For more info see [here](https://leaningtech.com/cheerpj-applet-runner/).

Comment: (Please accept my apologies for writing here, I didn't figure out how to send a private message) CheerpJ Applet Runner supports applets compiled by the new jdk-21? Tried here and found "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist". Thank you. Congratulations for your job. If you prefer I can delete this message after your consideration. Thanks.

Comment: CheerpJ does currently only support Java 8, but we plan to introduce support for more modern versions of Java after the 3.0 release.

If you are working with an applet it's quite likely that you can compile the code with JDK8, and have it working on CheerpJ today. Consider joining our Discord for further help: https://discord.gg/CHeATR6E9k

Comment: Very appreciated Alex, thank you. Sorry to take your time, my friend. In fact, JDK8 is perfect for my case! Thank you for your enlightenment, solved a big matter here. Big thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Applet Runner](https://www.japplis.com/applet-runner/) plug-ins for [IntelliJ/JetBrains](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16682-applet-runner), [NetBeans](https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/catalogue/?id=57) or [Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/applet-runner-eclipse).

Full disclosure, I'm the developer of the plug-ins.

The plug-ins are free, even for commercial use. There is a pro version that lets you run the applets in a Java Swing frame without the need of an IDE.